# Running number in for-loop java iterator

Tags: java, iterator

I need help from you guys.

I am using a for loop via iterator in java. I want to add running number to the list.
My code is something like this.

```
Map item1 = new LinkedHashMap();
int intRunningNo = 0;

for(Iterator<Object> i = sr.getResultList().iterator();i.hasNext();){
   Object object = i.next();

   //How do i create a running no here.
   //I try intRunningNo + 1 is not working

   item1.put("field1", object.getName());
   item1.put("field2", object.getDescription());
}
```

Comment: What was the EXACT statement you tried to increment intRunningNo with?

Comment: just to get a better picture, you used intRunningNo += 1 and it did not work?

Comment: I want to have something like this inside the loop

item1.put("field0", intRunningNo + 1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of these should work

1. intRunningNo++
2. intRunningNo += 1
3. intRunningNo = intRunningNo + 1

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to add the intRunninNo to identify the key for Map, such as 'filed'+intRunningNo,

Then you can try the following code:

item1.put("field" + (++intRunningNo), object.getName())
item1.put("field" + (++intRunningNo), object.getDescription());

Answer (score 0):

Try

`for(Iterator<Object> i = sr.getResultList().iterator();i.hasNext();**intRunningNo++**)`

you can also put `intRunningNo++` in for loop body